# SQL Delete Query Foreign Key constraint

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, aspxgridview

I am trying to `Delete` record with primary key as foreign key in two tables. Everytime I try to run the query it gives me this error:

Query:

```
DELETE FROM BusinessPlus_Post
FROM BusinessPlus_Post 
INNER JOIN BusinessPlus_PostImage ON BusinessPlus_Post.Post_ID = BusinessPlus_PostImage.BusinessPlusPost_ID 
INNER JOIN BusinessPlus_PostTag ON BusinessPlus_Post.Post_ID = BusinessPlus_PostTag.BusinessPlusPost_ID
WHERE 
    (BusinessPlus_Post.Post_ID = 3) 
    AND (BusinessPlus_PostImage.BusinessPlusPost_ID = 3) 
    AND (BusinessPlus_PostTag.BusinessPlusPost_ID = 3)
```

Error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_BusinessPlusPostImage". The conflict Occurred in database
>   "BusinessPlus_AdminPanel_Database", table
>   "dbo.BusinessPlus_PostImage", column 'BusinessPlusPost_ID'. The
>   statement was terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you are only stating that you want to delete the `BusinessPlus_Post` record, but not the `BusinessPlus_PostImage` and `BusinessPlus_PostTag` records. This would lead to problems, as we then would have 'orphan' PostImage and PostTag records with no corresponding Post records.

Apparently, it is not possible to delete from multiple tables in SQL Server (it *is* supported in MySQL, for example).

You have to split your queries, and delete from the 'child' tables first:

```
DELETE FROM BusinessPlus_PostImage
  WHERE BusinessPlusPost_ID = 3

DELETE FROM BusinessPlus_PostTag
  WHERE BusinessPlusPost_ID = 3

DELETE FROM BusinessPlus_Post
  WHERE Post_ID = 3
```

Comment: You cannot delete from multiple tables in a single `DELETE` statement in SQL Server ....

Comment: it is not working that way either, the query executes but no effect on tables.

Comment: And you do get results when you do `SELECT * FROM BusinessPlus_PostImage
  WHERE BusinessPlusPost_ID = 3`?

Comment: You're using Entity Framework? In that case, use the available EF methods for deleting entities.

Comment: Should I skip SQL then ?

Comment: Yes - it is much easier and more failsafe. You can use raw SQL to perform complicated queries - this isn't one of them, despite the trouble you have with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_BusinessPlusPostImage". The conflict Occurred in database
>   "BusinessPlus_AdminPanel_Database", table
>   "dbo.BusinessPlus_PostImage", column 'BusinessPlusPost_ID'. The
>   statement was terminated.

Error denotes that you have data referencing the foreign ,hence you cannot delete.

Delete the datas in `BusinessPlus_AdminPanel_Database` table
`dbo.BusinessPlus_PostImage`, column `BusinessPlusPost_ID` ,and then try **delete**